# how to remove cordova-ms-adal plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova (ionic) for developing mobileapps. I want to remove a cordova plugin cordova-ms-adal. usually am using `ionic plugin rm <plugin name>`.but it did n't work for me. i also use `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ms-adal` command.it also not work for me. give me some way to remove this plugin.

Comment: Does it give you error in the terminal while you try to remove it or is it not removed in the final build?

Answer (score 0):

```
npm uninstall cordova-plugin-ms-adal
```

try this (y)